# Return values based on multiple related counts

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I'm looking for a query that will return those account numbers with only one personal customer, who is not an owner, and two or more corporate customers, who are also not owners.

So for the data below, it should return '103'.

```
ACCNO  CUST_ID  OWNER     TYPE
 101     ABB      N     Personal
 101     CDD      N     Personal
 101     EFF      N     Corporate
 103     GHH      N     Personal
 103     IJJ      N     Corporate
 103     KLL      N     Corporate
 103     MNN      N     Corporate
 105     OPP      Y     Personal
 105     QRR      N     Corporate
 105     STT      N     Corporate
 106     UVV      Y     Personal
 106     WXX      Y     Corporate
 107     YZZ      N     Personal
 107     XYY      N     Corporate
```

It feels like multiple counts need to be carried out, with a condition linking them together, followed by a distinct on the account numbers, but I'm stuck about where to start with it.

To summarise, if it helps:

Return account numbers where count(Type=Personal and Owner=N)=1 and count(Type=Corporate and Owner=N)>1

Comment: I mis-phrased the statement, it was supposed to also specify that there were no corporate customers who were owners - I assumed that case would be covered by the existing statements but it needed to be added explicitly. So both the answers worked but I had to tweak them for my needs because I hadn't specified my question well enough. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to group by having a count.  An example

```
   select accno
from table1
where type = 'Corporate' and owner = 'N'
and accno in (
     select accno
     from table1
     where type = 'Personal' and owner = 'N'
     group by accno
     having count(*) = 1
)
group by accno
having count(*) > 1;
```

You can find the sqlfiddle of this here based on your data:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/416bfb/11

Comment: That's kind of what I had in my head but I would never have got there. :) Is there no way to do it with a single select statement, or do you pretty much have to check for the first condition, and then compare the second condition to the results from the first condition?

Comment: Never seen sqlfiddle before either, looks like a useful site.

Answer (score 1):

The "summary" in your OP is the answer itself. Use `COUNT(CASE ...)` to count values based on some criteria and use this inside `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT accno
FROM table1
WHERE owner = 'N'
GROUP BY accno
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Personal' THEN 1 END) = 1
AND COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Corporate' THEN 1 END) >= 2;
```

Comment: Thank you, I've not used CASE for a while - will try both solutions and see which works best.

Comment: Thanks, I selected this as the answer because it enabled me to embed the conditions into the existing query.